# How to write 'km/h' in Italian?

Tags: word-usage

We write kilometer as km. How do I write chilometro in Italian?
Also in English I write 'km/h' (km/hour). How to write it in Italian?
Can I write `km/ora`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by «How do I write chilometro in Italian?» you mean how do you abbreviate it, remember that the symbols for physical quantities (as for chemical elements etc.) are international standards. So: [km](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/km/) (see also the “[*chilometro*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chilometro/)” entry). Analogously for [km/h](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/km-h/).

Anyway, any English-Italian or Italian monolingual dictionary could answer such a question.

Comment: I'd also add: don't write km/ora. 

You can write either chilometri orari or km/h.

Comment: Bravo. I'm glad to see you answering the questions of some beginners.